# Erro após hospedar site

Tags: php

Estou com um problema e não sei resolve-lo. Eu e meus colegas de faculdade criamos um site em *PHP* em localhost claro, quando hospedamos ele exibe o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in
>   /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/loader.php
>   on line 19
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in
>   /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/loader.php
>   on line 19
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in
>   /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/loader.php
>   on line 19
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant **DIR** - assumed '**DIR**' in
>   /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/loader.php
>   on line 19

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda? Precisamos entregar esse trabalho essa semana.

Aqui está o trecho do código da linha 19

```
function __autoload($className) {

    $r = new RouterController;

    //procura primeiro na raiz da app
    $classpath = array('Lib', 'helpers', 'Model', 'Controller');
    $classFile = $className . ".php";
    $loaded = false;
    $mod_path = __DIR__ . "/$path" . "/$classFile";

    if (is_readable("$mod_path")) {
        require "$mod_path";
        $loaded = true;
        break;
        //return false;
    }

    if (is_readable("$path$classFile")) {
        require "$path$classFile";
        $loaded = true;
        break;
        //return false;
    }

}       

$reserved = array('finfo');

if ($loaded == false && !in_array("$className", $reserved)) {
    $baseurl = $r->base();
    //@Router::redirect("$baseurl/404.php?return=$baseurl");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Vocês não definiram a constante `DIR`, vide mensagem de erro: *Use of undefined constant DIR*.

Comment: Não seria um erro, como a própria mensagem dia Notice, porém você poderia utilizar o dirname(__FILE__) em vez de __DIR__

Comment: tem que mudar a variáveis de localhost para as do serverhost ou verificar a versão dophp como trocar dir por dirname(file) como o colega mencionou por exemplo

Comment: Agora apareceu esses:

Notice: Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' in /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/loader.php on line 19

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/Controller/index.php on line 7

Comment: O que esse `DIR` faz? Vocês que definiram? Qual é o objetivo dele e como é utilizado? Por favor, [edit] a pergunta e adicionar esses detalhes.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com o trecho de código referente a  "/home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/loader.php on line 19"

Comment: @MárvinEdge eu formatei o seu código ali na pergunta, mas perceba que ela está errada. A função é finalizada e ainda há código após que imagino que deveria ir dentro da função. Confirme se é desta forma que está no seu código mesmo.

Comment: sua $baseurl está definida como?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa constante `__DIR__` existe apenas a partir da versão 5.3.0 do PHP.

Talvez o erro seja porque o localhost tenha essa versão, ou superior, instalada, mas a hospedagem final não tenha.

EDITADO:

Se não teiver como atualizar a versão da hospedagem final, faça como bem sugeriu o Otto e use `dirname(__FILE__)` em vez de `__DIR__`.

Comment: O erro do DIR foi resolvido, só apareceu uma outra linha                

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/storage/2/3e/eb/noticiasdasgerais/public_html/yteste/Controller/index.php on line 7

Comment: O que está na linha 7? Poderia publicar o código do index.php?